# what muscles should be present in a ny strip steak?

Tags: beef

I was delivered some NY steaks, but they don't look like what I'm used to. Usually the NY seems to have one muscle, but these seem to have another muscle (highlighted in yellow). Would these still be considered NY? Any info is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Just looks like marbling to me

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I have no way to be sure, but those don't really look like NY strips. They look more like what we often see sold as petite sirloin steaks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a NY strip. The "strip loin" is like two feet+ long and at least 3/4 of it is what you're used to seeing. The last four or so steaks include an additional muscle or two at the "top." You got those last few steaks. (SOURCE: I'm a butcher ;)

Comment: The second muscle is often referred to as a cap. There is a layer of Silver-skin between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Those don't look like New York strips to me - normally a New York strip is either one solid muscle, or has a diagonal muscle right at the corner, even if well-marbled:

[image]

I've never seen one with a clear divide across the middle like that; IMO, someone is substituting a cheaper cut (perhaps sirloin, as another poster suggested) and palming it off as New York strip.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the brisket I buy to cut into steaks. I buy the brisket for about $2.50/lb. The meat is tough, but I baste the heck out of it to make it chewable.